# What's wrong with 'yarn watch' when I follow the Tensorflow.js getting started tutorial?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I executed 'yarn watch' in getting-started directory and this happend:

yarn run v1.22.19
$ npm run build && node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server dist -p 1234

> tfjs-examples-micro@0.1.0 build
> mkdir -p dist/ && cp index.html dist/ && cp index.js dist/

The syntax of the command is incorrect.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

I'm on Windows 11

I followed the tutorial to the letter and got this error, I was expecting the model example to run

Answer (score 2):

I also had faced the same situation while executing 'yarn watch' from my Windows 11 machine.  After few tries, made it to work by taking these steps.

1.Edited "package.json" and updated the following lines from

```
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "npm run build && node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server dist -p 1234 ",
    "build": "mkdir -p dist/ && cp index.html dist/ && cp index.js dist/"
  },
```

to

```
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "npm run build && http-server dist -p 1234 ",
    "build": "mkdir dist && copy index.html dist && copy index.js dist"
  },
```

2.Installed http-server separately through

> npm install -g http-server

as I was having troubles with running http-server from "node_modules/http-server/bin".  If http-server is working fine for you without installing it separately, please discard this step.

3.Then executed "yarn watch" and it worked like a charm.

Only problem here is that, each time before you run "yarn watch", you will have to manually remove the "dist" folder. May be we can include a directory removal command also in the "package.json" to avoid manual removal of this folder.

Hope this helps.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by :

Launching individually each subcommand of the build script
for linux

- mkdir -p dist/
- cp index.html dist/
- cp index.js dist/

for windows

- mkdir -p dist
- copy index.html dist
- copy index.js dist

And then this command to start the server

- http-server dist -p 1234